# I cannot use this method from this fragment activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, layout-inflater

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
   'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a
   null object reference at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:219)
   at com.Infoniq.restaurantapp.Fragment.HomepageFragment.Alertdailg(HomepageFragment.java:148) 
   at com.Infoniq.restaurantapp.Fragment.LoginPatternFragment$1.run(LoginPatternFragment.java:116)
```

**LoginPatternFragment.java**

```
if (response.contains("Successfully")) {
    final HomepageFragment hpf=new HomepageFragment();
    hpf.Alertdailg();
}
```

**HomepageFragment.java**

```
public void Alertdailg() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View prmpview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.billmode_alert, null);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `getActivity()` in HomepageFragment before it is attached to activity.

You need to attach it first, using FragmentManager, like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction();
HomepageFragment hpf = new HomepageFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, hpf);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
hpf.Alertdailg()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` objects have a lifecycle which is tied to the `Activity` which is displaying it.  When you call `new` you have just created the object but not attached it at all.  You'll need to add it to the `Activity` using the `FragmentManager`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
HomepageFragment hpf = new HomepageFragment();
ft.add(R.id.container, hpf);
ft.commit();
```

However, you still cannot call the `Alertdailg()` method at this point since the `Fragment` has still not gone through its lifecycle yet.  If you always wish to display this dialog when the `Fragment` is first displayed, you'll need to do this in the `onResume()` callback of the `Fragment`.  At that time the `Activity` will be attached.  You can also get the `Activity` in the `onAttach()` method of the `Fragment`.  Until that callback is executed, the `Fragment` is not attached.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference of the Parent Activity context. For that first you need to create a local context variable.

```
private Context context;
```

Then get the reference of the context when your fragment gets attached to the FragmentActivity. See the code.

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
    }
```

Now pass your local context variable to your AlertDialog(Context context) method and use it.